# Sum Total of 2 columns MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to improve my queries by making them work with the result they already have to make a total SUM of two columns

This query is an example of what I need, the result `RecargaronRetiraron` is the sum of (`Recargaron + Retiraron`)

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(Fecha_Procesa, '%d-%m-%y') AS Fecha,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN Tipo=1 AND Status =1 THEN Usuario END )) AS Recargaron,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN Tipo=2 AND Status =1 THEN Usuario END )) AS Retiraron,
    SUM(Recargaron + Recargaron) AS RecargaronRetiraron
FROM 
    transaccionesrr 
WHERE 
    Fecha_Procesa BETWEEN '2018-12-01' AND '2018-12-22' 
GROUP BY 
    DATE_FORMAT(Fecha_Procesa, '%d-%m-%y')  
ORDER BY 
    Fecha_Procesa;
```

This is the result that i get, it have a GROUP BY each day, i want the SUM of this two columns in the column "Total"

[image]

This is the query I'm using right now which work but I feel that it have to make a `COUNT` again the table and it just need to `SUM(Recargaron + Retiraron)`

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(Fecha_Procesa, '%d-%m-%y') AS Fecha,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN Tipo=1 AND Status =1 THEN Usuario END )) AS Recargaron,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN Tipo=2 AND Status =1 THEN Usuario END )) AS Retiraron,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN Status =1 THEN Usuario END )) AS RecargaronRetiraron,
FROM 
    transaccionesrr 
WHERE 
    Fecha_Procesa BETWEEN '2018-12-01' AND '2018-12-22' 
GROUP BY 
    DATE_FORMAT(Fecha_Procesa, '%d-%m-%y')  
ORDER BY 
    Fecha_Procesa;
```

This is just a part of the query the one that i have right now have a lot of columns with their totals and i think it should work faster if there is a way to do it like this.

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION:**

I found possible solution for my question. By using nested select I was able to remove the third COUNT that i had in my previous query

```
SELECT 
    res.fecha, 
    res.Recargaron, 
    res.Retiraron,
    SUM(res.Recargaron + res.Retiraron) as RecargaronRetiraron
FROM
    (SELECT 
         DATE_FORMAT(Fecha_Procesa, '%d-%m-%y') AS Fecha,
         COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN Tipo=1 AND Status =1 THEN Usuario END )) AS Recargaron,
         COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN Tipo=2 AND Status =1 THEN Usuario END )) AS Retiraron
     FROM 
         transaccionesrr 
     WHERE 
         Fecha_Procesa BETWEEN '2018-12-01' AND '2018-12-22' 
     GROUP BY 
         DATE_FORMAT(Fecha_Procesa, '%d-%m-%y') 
     ORDER BY 
         Fecha_Procesa) AS res
GROUP BY 
    DATE_FORMAT(res.fecha, '%d-%m-%y');
```

There seems to be an improvement in time but is not what I expected it to be.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `SUM(DISTINCT)` combined with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Fecha_Procesa, '%d-%m-%y') AS Fecha,
  COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN Tipo=1 AND Status=1 THEN Usuario END)) AS Recargaron,
  COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN Tipo=2 AND Status=1 THEN Usuario END)) AS Retiraron,
  SUM(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN Tipo IN(1,2) AND Status=1 THEN Usuario END)) 
      AS RecargaronRetiraron
FROM transaccionesrr 
WHERE Fecha_Procesa BETWEEN '2018-12-01' AND '2018-12-22' 
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(Fecha_Procesa, '%d-%m-%y')  
ORDER BY Fecha_Procesa;
```

Sidenote: You could also move condition `Status=1` directly to `WHERE` clasue:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Fecha_Procesa, '%d-%m-%y') AS Fecha,
  COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN Tipo=1 THEN Usuario END)) AS Recargaron,
  COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN Tipo=2 THEN Usuario END)) AS Retiraron,
  SUM(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN Tipo IN(1,2) THEN Usuario END)) AS RecagaronRetiraron
FROM transaccionesrr 
WHERE Fecha_Procesa BETWEEN '2018-12-01' AND '2018-12-22' 
  AND Status = 1
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(Fecha_Procesa, '%d-%m-%y')  
ORDER BY Fecha_Procesa;
```

Comment: Your code is missing a space here: `CASE WHEN TipoIN` but the solution works +1

Comment: @digijay Thanks for spotting it. Fixed :)